# Linux: set command for local variables

Tags: bash, shell, variable

I am trying to understand local/environment variables and export/set commands.

```
$ set FILEM="razrax"
$ echo $FILEM

$ FILEN="test"
$ echo $FILEN
test
```

Please explain why `echo $FILEM` returns empty string

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're confusing `bash` with `csh`.

In `bash` like in any Bourne-like shell, [`set`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html) is the command to *set* options (shell configuration settings like `-f`, `-C`, `-o noclobber`...) and positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`...).

```
set FILEM="razrax"
```

Sets `$1` to `FILEM=razrax`.

```
$ set FILEM="razrax"
$ echo "$1"
FILEM=razrax
```

The syntax for variable assignment in Bourne-like shells is:

```
VAR=value
```

(no space allowed on either side of `=`).

`ksh` and some other Bourne-like shells (mksh, pdksh, zsh) can also assign array variables with `set` though:

```
set -A array value1 value2
```

`zsh`, `bash`, `yash` and newer versions of `ksh` use this syntax instead:

```
array=(value1 value2)
```

In contrast, in `csh` or `tcsh`, the syntax is:

```
set VAR = value
set array = (value1 value2)
```

(spaces around `=` optional).

In `rc`/`es` shells:

```
VAR = value
array = (value1 value2)
```

(spaces around `=` optional).

Comment: Thank you for nice answer. The only thing I din't understand is what the difference benweet options and local variables "set is the command to set options"?

Comment: @iJava, `set -C` sets the `-C` option  (same as `set -o noclobber`). `set foo` assigns `foo` to `$1` (and `$#` is 1, (`$2`, `$3` are unset if previously set)). Check your shell's manual for details.

Comment: I don't understand what ARE options. Are these options that are send to programs like main (String[] args)? Or what? Where are they used?

Comment: @iJava, they are settings that affect the shell's behaviour. Again, [RTFM](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html)